# Определить номера рядов

Tags: php

http://ideone.com/CzLlJH

```
<?php
$count = 15;
$row_count = 3;

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo '
        <div class="row{NUM}">
            '.$i.'
        </div>
    ';
}
?>
```

Необходимо чтобы на первых трёх элементах был `class="row1"`, на следующих трёх `class="row2"` и т.д..

Пример:

```
<div class="row1">
    0
</div>

<div class="row1">
    1
</div>

<div class="row1">
    2
</div>

<div class="row2">
    3
</div>

<div class="row2">
    4
</div>

<div class="row2">
    5
</div>

<div class="row3">
    6
</div>

<div class="row3">
    7
</div>

<div class="row3">
    8
</div>
```

Comment: хороший отдых, судя по всему! : )  `$row = floor($i/3)+1;`  [Ideone](http://ideone.com/6ctAlZ)

Comment: @Sergiks, не то слово прям :D Отлично всё работает, превратите комментарий в ответ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы на 3 шага `$i`, `$row` делала всего 1 – надо округлять до целого результат деления $i на 3:

```
$i  floor($i/3)
0   0  
1   0
2   0
3   1
4   1
5   1
```

В вашей задаче отсчёт строк не от 0, а от 1, поэтому +1:

```
$row = floor($i/3)+1;
```

Итого, рекомендуемый код:

```
<?php
$count = 15;
$row_count = 3;

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $row = floor( $i / $row_count) + 1;
    printf('<div class="row%d">%d</div>'.PHP_EOL, $row, $i);
}
```

Запустить этот код [на Ideone](http://ideone.com/6ctAlZ).

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом

```
<?php
$count = 15;
$row_count = 3;

for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $num = floor($i / $row_count) + 1;
    echo '
        <div class="row'.$num.'">
            '.$i.'
        </div>
    ';
}
```